# TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable - python

Tags: python

Well this python program is meant to take 2 numbers from the user, one is the multiplication table it's meant to go up in so the increment, and one is the number it should stop at. This is the program so far:

```
count = 0

UI = 0

UserInput = 10

print ("Please type a number and press enter, this will be the multiplication table your sequence will go up in, then type another number and press enter, this will be the number the sequence will stop at.")

UI = int(input(""))

UserInput = int(input(""))

print = ("The program will now display all the numbers between your two numbers")

while all [count <= UserInput]:

      count = count*UI

      print (count)
```

But it keeps on saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Shahriyar/Documents/DiffProg.py", line 11, in <module>
    while all [count <= UserInput]:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

How do I fix it? and please don't suggest I use a for loop because this is for school and we're meant to use a while loop

Comment: Format your code properly

Comment: `while all [count <= UserInput]:` is invalid.

Comment: while all [count <= UserInput] - you are inventing new syntax...next in line.

Comment: Lots of nonsense in this code. Why you assigning print to a string?

Comment: You are inventing your own DSL?

Answer (score 1):

"it keeps on saying":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Shahriyar/Documents/DiffProg.py", line 11, in <module>
    while all [count <= UserInput]:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

because the line of code it reproduces, `while all [count <= UserInput]:` is not syntactically valid. It's not a thing in python.

You probably want `while count <= UserInput:`.

There are other errors in your code. See if you can find them using testing.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking a look at the following python documentation:

http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#while

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html